# Multiplos Controlers com JavaFX 2, como um referenciar a instancia do outro

Tags: java, design-pattern, javafx

**ATUALIZADO.**

Estou criando uma nova aplicação em Java usando JavaFX, quando programava com Swing tinha o costume de criar múltiplos controladores especializados para a interface, e no Swing uso um controlador que tem conhecimento de todos os outros e assim com métodos lazy carrego cada um conforme necessário, e descarto quando absoluta certeza que não vou precisar mais, por exemplo quando quando o respectivo View é descartado.

Já percebi que o JavaFX cuida de certa forma da criação do `Controller` para mim, porém não descobri como faço para um Controlador secundário ter conhecimento do principal. E pior há casos que tenho o mesmo `Controller` em diversos `Viewers.

Por exemplo ao abrir um novo painel através de um menu ou ao clicar um botão, como faço para o controlador deste novo painel ter acesso a atual instancia do controlador do painel anterior que foi responsável por abrir este novo.

No segundo caso, tendo o mesmo controlador para dois `Viewers` diferente, como controlar que sejam um `Singleton` (a mesma instância para ambos)?

O código usado hoje para obter os controladores é o seguinte:

```
SocialStreamController getSocialStreamController() {
    if (socialStreamController == null) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("../view/SocialStreamView.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(resource);

        try {
            socialStreamView = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        socialStreamController = loader.getController();
        socialStreamController.setMainControler(this);

    }
    return socialStreamController;
}
```

O que tem me incomodado é que preciso carregar o `Viewer` para obter o controlador, e se eu inverter e passar a injetar o controlador pelo código, perco a funcionalidade de obter referências automáticas aos `Handlers` definidos internamente em cada controlador.

Sempre procuro manter uma hierarquia onde o controlador mais especializado e mais interno na aplicação tem conhecimento do anterior, no qual foi responsável pela sua ativação.

Além disso, há casos onde certos controladores precisam acessar funções e handlers de outros controladores como posso incluir tais referências a outros controladores?

Comment: Eu achei a solução usando Jboss WELD com CDI, mais um pouco de código, ficou excelente, porém complexo para responder imediatamente de forma resumida e prática, estarei escrevendo como fiz e assim que tiver tempo posto.

Caso o número de pessoas que se interesse pela solução seja interessante, eu adianto a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez isso te ajude, o controlador pode ser criados sem estar diretamente ligado ao fxml. Dessa forma você pode criar um construtor e passar como parâmetro qualquer objeto que ele necessite. Pra isso no fxml você remove o atributo que define a classe controller, e o define de forma programática, seu método para mudaria para algo parecido com isso:

```
SocialStreamController getSocialStreamController() {
    if (socialStreamController == null) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("../view/SocialStreamView.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(resource);
        socialStreamController = new SocialStreamController(<parametros aqui!>);
        loader.setController(socialStreamController);
        try {
            socialStreamView = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return socialStreamController;
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Parece que você está enfrentando um problema para obter informações de uma página anterior em seu aplicativo. A solução que você encontrou foi criar um pacote chamado "models" e dentro dele criar um arquivo (por exemplo, "Dados.java") para criar objetos que armazenam essas informações. Em seguida, você pode acessar esses objetos na próxima página ou em qualquer lugar necessário.

Se ainda estiver interessado, posso fornecer o código completo. O trecho de código que você compartilhou sugere que você está obtendo um objeto do tipo "Usuario" da instância principal do seu aplicativo e, em seguida, chamando o método "loadDados()" para obter os dados associados a esse usuário. Você pode usar esses dados na próxima tela do seu aplicativo.

```java
// Obtendo o objeto Usuario da instância principal
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) Main.getInstance().getStage().getUserData();

// Carregando os dados do usuário
String dados = usuario.loadDados();
```

Esse código presumivelmente é usado para recuperar informações específicas do usuário e utilizá-las na próxima tela do aplicativo. Se precisar de mais detalhes ou do código completo, estou à disposição para ajudar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).